# Date must be more than 2 Years from today

Tags: calculated-column-formula, date-time, sharepoint-list, column-validation, list-validation

I have a date column in a SharePoint list. This column need to be filled with dates that 2 years forward from today or more.

How can I write the validation formula for this?

Much appreciated if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
 =[Date Column] > DATE(YEAR(Today())+2,MONTH(Today()),DAY(Today()))
```

Read more about column validations in SharePoint at:

[SharePoint Online List Column Validation Examples](https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-online-list-column-validation-examples/).

Comment: Thank you. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: Welcome. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.